# how to use connection pooling for creating publisher in JMs using activeMQ

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am using following code for creating publisher every time when i need to add message in topic i will run this , but some time it gives error

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://" + ip + ":" + port );           
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.setClientID(publisherName);

PooledConnectionFactory pf = new PooledConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
pf.setMaxConnections(1000);

Session session = connection.createSession(false,session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Topic topic = session.createTopic(TopicName);
MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(topic);
```

Error:

```
javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: localhost - Client: AthenaPublisher already connected from tcp://127.0.0.1:44448
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please insert your code as code

Answer (score 0):

Using a pool when setting the client ID will inevitably lead to such errors as you can have only one connection with a given client ID connected to the broker at any given time.  In your case you are configuring the pool for 1000 pooled connections so it will happen pretty often that a new connection will be created and the error you've given will be produced.  You need to either not use pooling or use a pool with only 1 pooled connection that shares session level resources with you code.